# Error when installing TexLive from the internet. Unexpected EOF in archive

Tags: errors, installing, texlive

I'm a new user of Texlive, and I'm trying to download it from the internet using the first link provided by this page: https://www.tug.org/texlive/
When I get to the installation of the cm-super package, I get this error

```
./tlpkg/installer/xz/xzdec.i386-linux: (stdin): File is corrupt
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
untar: untarring /usr/local/texlive/2013/temp/cm-super.tar failed (in         /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist)
untarring /usr/local/texlive/2013/temp/cm-super.tar failed, stopping install.
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
./install-tl: Writing log in current directory: /home/josh/Downloads/install-tl-20140407/install-tl.
```

I get the same everytime I try to restart the installation. I have read other posts about it and they recommend downloading the .iso file, but since my internet connection is very slow, it'd be hard for me to get it.

Is there any way to fix it, like downloading the package manually and then tell the installer to skip that package, or something like that?

P.S: I'm using Linux Mint 15 Olivia

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using this: https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: Yes. Apparently the closest mirror for me is in Costa Rica. I am now trying to start the installation using the following command:

sudo ./install-tl --location http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/

Comment: I should've known it wouldn't work. The installer was already using that mirror.

Comment: I would suggest selecting another mirror, even if it doesn't seem to be the closest one. Also, even if your internet connection is slow or disconnecting frequently, you could use a downloader with resume capabilities (like wget) to download the .iso file.

Comment: I actually don't really know if it can handle unstable connections (it should), but why aren't you using your package manager?

Comment: Using another mirror worked fine. The installation was succesfull, but now I have a new problem.
I can not use tlmgr, and when my TeX editor (TeXMaker) doesn't find the packages installed by TeXLive